# Docker Compose, use COMPOSE_ENV_FILES instead of --env-file not working as expected

Tags: docker-compose

### Description of the issue

I would like to not use on the command line the option --env-file .env.myfile but rather the environment variable COMPOSE_ENV_FILES but it does not work.
All the environment variables in the docker-compose.yml are set to empty string, it seems to me this environment variable is more to set the env-files list.

I have thought the env variables works like COMPOSE_PROFILES, that is avoid to pass values on the command line but instead using an environment variable but it seems not like this.

Any idea?

I have set the env varibale but the environment variables in the docker-compose.yml are set to empty string.

### Command

```bash
$ export COMPOSE_PROFILES=profile1,profile2
$ export COMPOSE_FILE=file1.yml:file2.yml
$ export COMPOSE_ENV_FILES=env.common,env.qa

$ docker compose up
```

Comment: Please update the question to show us the specific commands you're using to bring up your compose application.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have forgotten, done :-)

Comment: I have the exact same issue, COMPOSE_ENV_FILES does not work